# Using trapezium rule to find area

Tags: integration

I have the question:

[image]

For part (a) I got 10.449 and 3.357
[image]

For part (b) I got 8.68 with the following working:

[image]

Is my answer for part (b) correct ? And if not could you point out at which point I went wrong ?

Comment: As a good check:$$\int_4^5\sqrt{x^3+2}\ dx=9.66565469368$$which means you did something wrong (likely missed something that came out to be $\approx+1$), as the trapezoidal sum should over-estimate, not under-estimate.

Comment: We may also notice that the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality provides an extremely accurate approximation: $$\frac{2}{5} \sqrt{3739-1411 \sqrt{5}}=\color{green}{9.6656}76\ldots$$

Comment: Why the votes to close as not having enough context?  As I see it, there is plenty of context here.

Comment: Yh I have tried to include as much context as possible even showed all my working out (:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made an error in part a).  Notice that

$$f(5)=\sqrt{2+5^3}=\sqrt{127}>\sqrt{121}=11$$

So it must be something slightly larger than $11$.  Other than that, the set-up everywhere looks fine.

Comment: Thanks (: so the final answer I get is 9.67 is this correct ?

Comment: @Dan That is what I got :-)

Answer (score 1):

I cannot grasp the actual purpose of such kind of exercises, the idea of the trapezoid method is simple to understand, performing it by hand is just tedious, very error-prone and quite useless, in my personal opinion. Anyway, over the interval $[4,5]$ the function $f(x)=\sqrt{x^3+2}$ behaves like $x^{3/2}$, hence by the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality
$$ \int_{4}^{5}x^{3/4}\sqrt{\frac{x^3+2}{x^{3/2}}}\,dx \approx\sqrt{\int_{4}^{5}x^{3/2}\,dx \int_{4}^{5}\frac{x^3+2}{x^{3/2}}\,dx} = \frac{2}{5} \sqrt{3739-1411 \sqrt{5}}$$
and the RHS is about $9+\frac{2}{3}$. That suggests there is an off-by-one in your computations.
The trapezoid method should give you
$$ \int_{4}^{5}x^{3/4}\sqrt{\frac{x^3+2}{x^{3/2}}}\,dx\approx\frac{\frac{1}{2}f\left(\frac{16}{4}\right)+f\left(\frac{17}{4}\right)+f\left(\frac{18}{4}\right)+f\left(\frac{19}{4}\right)+\frac{1}{2}f\left(\frac{20}{4}\right)}{4}$$
that is close to $9+\frac{2}{3}$ as well.

Comment: Many elementary calculus courses just give questions like this to illustrate the behavior of certain quadrature rules. I just don't agree with the choice of function here.